# Is there a good deployment module using Golang's amazing single binary compilation model?

Tags: machine-learning-model

From my limited understanding, it's quite annoying trying to deploy models like PyTorch. So one would need something like ONNX.

But another approach like Golang with a single binary is VERY attractive. I have used Golang before and it's reasonably fast and compiles to one binary easily. For Rust, compiling to a single binary is a nightmare.

So I wonder if anyone has seen work that translates XGBoost trees to Golang and uses arrow as the data exchange format? That way, it makes deployment super easy, wouldn't it?

Comment: Have you looked at BentoML?

Comment: I dont need a service. I already have a service, I just need the deployment artifact.

Answer (score 1):

I code up a Golang package call [gotch](https://github.com/sugarme/gotch) that can take Pytorch pretrained model and do further training/finetuning or inferring.
Have a look at “example” subfolder as well as Gophernotes notebook links in README.md.